# SSRS Multi-Select Parameters exact match

Tags: reporting-services, reporting

I am trying to develop visibility option for columns from dataset. 
There is parameter with "Alow multiple option" that I use in expression:

```
=IIF(InStr(JOIN(Parameters!DispColumns.Label, ","), "Label") > 0, False, True)
```

But If I have Items in dropdown list with the same words then expression makes visible columns even they were not chosen.

Let's say we have the next list of labels:

- Label1
- .....
- Current Index
- Index
- .....
- LabelN

I'm choosing Index column in list and want to see just "Current Index" column but I will see both of them. (Current Index + Index) because InStr will return value for "Index" column.

What should I use for exact match ?

Answer (score 0):

I would use Pipes ( | ) as the separator for each item and them include them in the search function. This would ensure that **only** the **whole** name would match.

```
=IIF(InStr("|" & JOIN(Parameters!DispColumns.Label, ",") & "|", "|" & "Label" & "|") > 0, False, True)
```